# Colored status border missing in MS Teams Notifications sent from Jenkins

Tags: notifications, microsoft-teams, jenkins

We have a Jenkins Connector configured to receive build notifications. In the past, the Jenkins notifications have been displayed in Teams with a colored border line showing the build status (red = failed, green = success).

The colored border line can be seen in the Microsoft documentation page "Stay up to date on your build activities with Jenkins integration in Microsoft Teams" (in the last screenshot)

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams-blog/stay-up-to-date-on-your-build-activities-with-jenkins/ba-p/467440

The colored border line is missing now, for unknown reasons. (it may be caused by an Teams update or a Windows update)

[image: Jenkins notification]

---

Update: meanwhile there was a change, now the Jenkins notifications indicate the build status in the first line, so it is immediately visible again. (screenshot will follow)

Comment: I see the same thing on the OSX new "Teams (work or school)" Client, as well as the Web client. Suddenly the colors are missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like unfortunately Microsoft dropped support for messege card theme color in the "New Teams":

> We have updated card styles and theme color has been deprecated in card boarders. So, this is expected. This is by design.

source: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/10062#issuecomment-1862178211

This is seriously criticized in the linked topic on GitHub, but the only answer from Microsoft so far, was to share the feedback with the engineering team.